# Что понимается в современной разработке под Continuous Inegration?

Tags: git, непрерывная-интеграция

Объясните, пожалуйста, что в современной разработке понимается под Continuous Integration? Может ли быть CI без CD (или CD без CI)? Какое отношение CI имеет к использованию в процессе разработки git (ветки для каждой задачи/фичи, актуализация веток)? И обязательно ли CI подразумевает командную/совместную разработку?

Comment: можете поискать просто что делают `DevOps` и поймете тогда суть CI/CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continuous Integration** - это то, что программисты постоянно что то делают, коммитят по много раз в день (вот он и git появился. С svn на больших проекта коммит может быть "долгим" (у меня в практике было пол часа), а мердж или сложная интеграция может потребовать заморозки изменений.), на серверах сборки это постоянно собирается, проганяется через тесты и тому подобное. Это дает то, что код у всех программистов приблизительно один и тот же, никто с своей веткой не уходит слишком далеко. А также, для менеджмента постоянно видно движение задач. Если кто то сделает багу, обычно тесты присекают достаточно быстро.

**Continuous Delivery** - это такая практика, когда код всегда готов быть отдан (заказчику или на сервер). То есть, обычно в мастере, всегда находится код, который был прогнан через разнообразные тесты и проверки и его можно безопасно "отдавать в прод". Рядышком ещё есть и **Continuous Deployment** - это тоже самое, но только с одним дополнительным шагом - если код прошел все проверки, то он сразу и в прод заливается.

Многие компании практикуют смешанный подход. К примеру, на тестовые сервера заливают автоматически, а на прод - только ручками, одобренный QA и менеджментом код.

> Может ли быть CI без CD

думаю может, но смысл? Это просто обычная разработка в большой компании, когда все писатели, а читателей нет. ("ты хоть код компилировал перед коммитом? а зачем?")

> (или CD без CI)?

если никто не коммитит, то код всегда готов к деплою. так что да.

> И обязательно ли CI подразумевает командную/совместную разработку?

если у программиста раздвоение личности, то он может и самостоятельно использовать CI/CD, что бы эффективно работать. Но обычно программист одиночка, если он взял большой проект, как то и сам справляется, без CI. А вот CD очень хорошо может помочь.

> Какое отношение CI имеет к использованию в процессе разработки git (ветки для каждой задачи/фичи, актуализация веток)?

ветки это один из способов помочь командной разработки, а "актуализация веток", как уже выяснили - маркетинговая фича неизветной конторы - гугл так и не смог ничего внятного сказать.

Comment: Спасибо, но только из вашего ответа не ясно, чем же все же отличается CD от CI. Если CI означает, что тесты прогоняются и упавшие тесты сразу присекаются, то получается что CI уже и обеспечивает что тесты пройдены и можно отдавать (заказчику или на сервер). Не могли бы Вы уточнить ответ?

Comment: тесты по средине. CI не подразумевает, что код будет доставлен заказчику. CI на самом деле не требует тестов, но они подразумеваются. Но может быть код ревью и другие методы (например, просто доверяем). CD не заморачивается на то, как пишется код. Его задача обеспечить инфраструктуру по доставке программы. То есть, для обычного программиста хороший CD выглядит так -  поле выбора версии и одна кнопка "залить в прод прям сейчас" и все. Ну может ещё кнопка "вернуть все назад, так как что то пошло не так". И вот это точно не CI.

Comment: Нашел хорошее описание http://lib.custis.ru/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F